# Get GA version of SDK?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I always download titanium SDK from [here](http://builds.appcelerator.com/#master)

There is only the versions without `GA` version
like

6.0.1.GA

5.5.2.GA

I think GA is patched version.

GA version is available only for subscription user?
(if so ,I will obey appcelerator policy)
Or Is it possible to make GA version by myself or download??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GA version is "General availability". It is not a patch version. Usually the 3rd number in a version indicates a patch version. It is a stable version though, a tested one. A production build. All others are nightly/beta's for example.

GA versions are also the ones that Appcelerator gives out, and that means you at least have to have an indie subscription to get them.

However, you can also download them yourselves using [tisdk](https://github.com/dbankier/tisdk) tool by dbankier.

So for example: `tisdk install 6.0.1.GA`

This is all great, since Titanium is open source and you obey any policy in place, no need to worry about that.

Answer (score 1):

you could simply use the terminal commands to download and install the required SDK's:

```
appc ti sdk install [<version>] [--default] [--force] [--branch <branch name>]
ex : appc ti sdk install 6.0.1.GA
```

if you want to see the list of SDK available for download you could use the below command line:

```
appc ti sdk list
```

Comment: appc needs licence. in this case I would like to use open source version.